# Permission Denied for shutil.copy

Tags: python, permission-denied, shutil

Why is it, that when I run this python code (even as administrator, and yes, I've checked the permissions beforehand), that it keeps telling me "Permission denied"? Could somebody please help me fix this.

```
import os
import shutil
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import zipfile

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()  

starting_zip_file = filedialog.askopenfilename()

if starting_zip_file:
    print(f"Selected file: {starting_zip_file}")
else:
    print("No file selected")
    exit(0)

destination_folder = r'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\folder1'
copy_folder = r'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\folder2'

parent_folder1 = destination_folder

new_folder_name = input("Enter the name of the new folder: ")


destination_path = os.path.join(parent_folder1, new_folder_name)

if not os.path.exists(destination_path):
    os.mkdir(destination_path)
    print(f"Folder '{new_folder_name}' created in '{parent_folder1}'.")
else:
    print(f"Folder '{new_folder_name}' already exists in '{parent_folder1}'.")

parent_folder2 = copy_folder
temp_folder = 'TEMP'
temp_folder_path = os.path.join(parent_folder2, temp_folder)

if not os.path.exists(temp_folder_path):
    os.mkdir(temp_folder_path)
    print(f"Folder 'TEMP' created in '{parent_folder2}'.")
else:
    print(f"Folder 'TEMP' already exists in '{parent_folder2}'.")

try:
    shutil.move(starting_zip_file, destination_path)
    print(f"File '{starting_zip_file}' moved")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"File '{starting_zip_file}' not found in the source folder.")
except PermissionError:
    print(f"Permission denied for file '{starting_zip_file}'. Check permissions.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred while moving file '{starting_zip_file}': {e}")

try:
    shutil.copyfile(destination_path, temp_folder_path)
    print(f"File '{starting_zip_file}' copied to 'TEMP' folder.")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"File '{starting_zip_file}' not found in the destination folder.")
except PermissionError:
    print(f"Permission denied for file '{starting_zip_file}'. Check permissions.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred while copying file '{starting_zip_file}': {e}")
```

As mentioned, I tried to check permissions, run as administrator, etc. It still didn't work.

Please help.

Comment: Please post the full output you get when it errors.

Comment: You should be able to create a [mre] that doesn't involve Tk.

Comment: Not sure if it is related but `r'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\folder1` looks wrong. the `r` should disable the backslash escapes. Just `r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\folder1'` should be enough

Comment: You checked the permissions, and what exactly was the result of that?

Answer (score 0):

try to move or copy the file without python, just use the win10 or linux,

then see what happen after you move or copy the file.